# Zapier Through Custom Error On Authentication

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am just getting started with Zapier and I am trying through an error message based on the response from the API.

The API we are working with always returns a Status 200, but in the response, it will tell if the response was a success or failure. Example:

```
if(response.status == "success") {
   //Succesful Action!
} else {
   //Something when Wrong/
}
```

My current Zapier authentication looks as such:

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://bw.bingewave.com/auth/login',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'X-EMAIL': bundle.authData.email,
    'X-PASSWORD': bundle.authData.password,
    'X-ORGANIZER-ID': bundle.authData.organizer_id
  },
  params: {

  },
  body: {
    'organizer_id': bundle.authData.organizer_id,
    'email': bundle.authData.email,
    'password': bundle.authData.password
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;
    
    if(results.status == "success"){

    } else {
        //What do I throw here? Where are the docs for this?
     }



    return results;
  });
```

How to I correctly throw the error when authentication fails for my Zapier integration?

Comment: Well I don't know how it will be done but you should read this  [Error Handling](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform/#error-handling)

Comment: Thanks! The docs helped, they just weren't easy to find